# I am trying to return largest sum of a 3x3 submatrix from a 6x6 matrix. It's running out of index. Can somebody point where I am messing up

Tags: java, matrix

I am trying to return the largest sum of a 3x3 submatrix froma 6x6 matrix but it runs out of bound.

```
    int sum=0 , count2=0, maxsum=0,count1=0;  
    for (int i =0;i<=3;i++)    { 
        for (int j=0;j<=3;j++)   { 
            for(int k=0+count1;k<=2+count1;k++)    {  
                 for (int l=0+count2;l<=2+count2;l++)    {   
                      sum+=arr[k][l];  
                 }
            }  
            System.out.println(sum);  
            if (sum>maxsum)    {
                 maxsum=sum;
             }  
             sum=0;
             count2++;  
        }   
        count1++;  
     }   
     System.out.println(maxsum);
```

Comment: There is only one place that you access your array `arr` so either the values of `k` or `l` exceed the size of the array - probably you want to check using `<` rather than `<=` as array indexes are zero based

Comment: thanks a lot , I figured it out. I forgot to reset count2.